# changing a div's value by a select's option

Tags: javascript, html

I have to write some code where in a select there are three options and the value of a div will change to the selected item's value when it is changed, I have tried quite a lot of methods and functions but nothing worked. this is my current code :

```js
$('select[class="country"]').on('change', function () {
    var get = $('select option:selected').text();
    $('#fDiv').text = get;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>The coolest country</h1>
<select name="country"id="country" class="country">
  <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
</select>
<div id="fDiv"></div>
```

Please share any ideas of what could be wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure javascript solution to your issue.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#country');
const div = document.querySelector('#fDiv');
div.innerHTML = select.selectedOptions[0].value // remove this if you dont want a value set initially
select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
   div.innerHTML = select.selectedOptions[0].value
});
```

```html
<h1>The coolest country</h1>
<select name="country"id="country" class="country">
  <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
</select>
<div id="fDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.text()` like : `$('#fDiv').text(myText);`

```js
$('select[class="country"]').on('change', function() {
  var myText = $('select option:selected').text();
  $('#fDiv').text(myText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>The coolest country</h1>
<select name="country" id="country" class="country">
  <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="Romania">Romania</option>

</select>
<div id="fDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you don't use the assignment =, you use it like ('#id').text(get):

```js
$('select[class="country"]').on('change', function() {
  var get = $('select option:selected').val();
  $('#fDiv').text(get);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>The coolest country</h1>
<select name="country" id="country" class="country">
  <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="Romania">Romania</option>

</select>
<div id="fDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `<html>` at the start of your file

2) Add a space in between `name = "country" id="country"`

3) Use text() with a parameter: such as `$('#fDiv').text(get);`

```js
  $('select[class="country"]').on('change', function () {
  var get = $('select option:selected').text();
  $('#fDiv').text(get);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cool Site</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>The coolest country</h1>
<select name="country" id="country" class="country">
<option value="Korea">Korea</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
</select>
<div id="fDiv"></div>


</body>
</html>
```